# Python Dictionary Comprehension accessing non-existent key

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to create a dictionary that would look like this if `n == 3`

```
{
  0: [1, 2],
  1: [0, 2],
  2: [0, 1]
}
```

Basically.. just a dict with keys that mapped to arrays that contained the other key integers except the one it was mapped to. My code:

```
import itertools

graph = {i: range(num_nodes) for i in range(num_nodes)}

for i in graph.keys():
    graph[i].remove(i)
```

I'm not sure why this error is being thrown `ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`

After a bit more research, found that I could do a subtraction between sets and do it all in one go:

`graph = {i: list(set(range(num_nodes)) - set([i])) for i in range(num_nodes)}`

Thanks everybody!

Comment: What's up with the `permutations` and `num_nodes - 1`? It looks like you could replace that whole expression for the values in the comprehension with `range(num_nodes)`.

Comment: You may have to parse the key to an int... `graph[i].remove(int(i))`?

Comment: It seems that you have a list of `itertools.permutations` iterables -- not a list of integers as you seem to expect.

Comment: @user2357112 you're right - i was mixing a procedure for another problem, which was permutations of pairs in the range like (0,1), (0,2). Updating the question. Thanks.

Comment: Your revised code seems to work for me and produce the output you want (after adding 1 to `num_nodes` to undo your mysterious subtraction of 1.)

Comment: Ahh, again, mixing code from other concern. Thanks for your analysis :)

Comment: The end of range is non inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `type(graph[i])` is not a `list`, its of type `range`. Convert it to a list and try this:

[Edit: removed subtraction, check sgarza62's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632146/python-dictionary-comprehension-accessing-non-existent-key#comment40048468_25632302)]

```
import itertools    

graph = {i: list(range(num_nodes)) for i in range(num_nodes)}

for i in graph.keys():
    graph[i].remove(i)
```

Comment: The OP seems to be using Python 2.  If the wrong type were the problem, the error message would be something like "range object does not have attribute 'remove'.".

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit confused by the other comments. It's clear!

Comment: @BenPoon Can you please clarify what version of python you are using?

Comment: Here, graph ends up being `{0: [1], 1: [0]}`.

Comment: @sgarza62 I was not looking at the value of num_nodes, you could either adjust that in the definition of num_nodes(add one there) or like you did, remove it from the range

Comment: @Ashwin Here's his original code, where `num_nodes = 3`: `graph = {i: list(itertools.permutations(range(num_nodes - 1), 2)) for i in range(num_nodes - 1)}`. I ran this code, and it was throwing a `ValueError`, because it looking for a value that didn't exist. OP fixed it in the question details.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.5

Comment: @sgarza62 ah! gotcha, then yes, the subtraction decreases the node.

Comment: Check his original code snippet in the edit history. Yes, it did.

Answer (score 1):

Prior to the edit, it was an off-by-one error.

```
import itertools

num_nodes = 3
graph = {i: range(num_nodes) for i in range(num_nodes)}

for i in graph.keys():
    graph[i].remove(i)

print graph
# {0: [1, 2], 1: [0, 2], 2: [0, 1]}
```

Comment: This code is now identical to the code in the question, since the question has been updated again.

Comment: After that question edit, the code in the question details is perfectly correct (it will no longer throw a `ValueError`). So this is no longer a question :-) Anyways, prior to the fix in the question details, this solved the problem. Glad he fixed it.

Comment: @sgarza62: Even before the last update, it did not throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a dict comprehension without an additional for loop, try this:

```
import itertools
num_nodes = 3

graph = {i: (range(num_nodes)[:i] + range(num_nodes)[i+1:]) for i in range(num_nodes)}
```

Note: Unfortunately, the list concatenation is necessary, as `list.remove(x)` does not return an updated list but changes the list in place and returns nothing. Thus, `range(num_nodes).remove(i-1)` cannot be directly used in the comprehension.